# Android emulator can't able to load the application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, web-services

I'm a newbie to android and was trying out an imported android application to integrate with an **third party web services** but it didn't worked out well and since then I'm not able to run any of the application I had in my eclipse workspace nor I see the application installed in the menu list of emulator. I tried setting up everything from scratch (**ADK**) but it didn't worked so can anybody suggest any solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: More information please, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Please provide what error appearing, are you using create new project with existing resource in eclipse? and for your trial on setting up from scratch, are you sure you have include all the resource, library and the manifest ?

Comment: The issue is that I don't get any error on eclipse console or anywhere else and previously the android emulator use to start with launched application but now the application doesn't execute or appear in menu list.

Answer (score 1):

ya it is very complex to setup Eclipse & plugins Android SDK & ADT i think [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) will help you out

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem with our app. The [App Dev Room](http://www.appdevroom.com) app required us to install the [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) to Eclipse before it would function correctly.